# Drill Down in WebI 4.1

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Let's say 2 fact tables `Employee_Fact` and `Manager_Fact` are available. And the dimension tables like `Organisation_Dim`, `Location_Dim`, `Department_Dim`, `Calender_Dim`.

`Employee_Fact` is connected with all the dimension Tables and `Manager_Fact` is connected with the alias of the same dimension tables.

In Report 1, I have a table that gives the `Organisation_Name`, `Department_Name`, `Employee_Salary`, `Manager Name` and `Manager Salary`. In this report I need the filter `Organisation Name`, `Region`. Also, the drill down from `Organisation Name --> Department Name --> Location --> Manager Name --> Employee Name`.

I have 2nd Report that shows the `Organisation Name`, `Department Name`, `Department Amount`, `Location Name`, no of Employee. Here I have drill down from `Organisation name --> Department name --> Location`.

How can I obtain drill down in this scenario? Do I need to add 2 different hierarchies or only one hierarchy is needed? This confusion occurred as I take values from both fact tables in 1st report.

Comment: You can certainly have multiple hierarchies.  What exactly is the problem that you're having?

Comment: @ joe: pls see my explained question and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake that I did not select the same drill down objects in my Report too. Rather I selected from other Class Folder which did not give correct hierarchy.

Thanks

Niki

Answer (score 1):

For the example you described, you would probably be better off **not** creating aliases of your conformed dimension tables, but instead joining all dimension tables to both fact tables, then creating two contexts.  One context would include all of the joins between `employee_fact` and the dimensions; the other context would include `manager_fact` and the dimensions.

If there are any dim tables that are not conformed, then they will simply be joined to only one fact table (and, accordingly, will only be in one context).

With this model, you can create a single query that includes measures from both facts, and attributes from one or more dim table.  The report engine will automatically create a separate SELECT query for each fact table; but it will be presented as a single block in the report.

You will also only need a single hierarchy since you no longer have multiple copies of dimensions.

Regarding your statement:

> I have 2nd Report that shows the Organisation Name,Department Name,
>   Department Amount, Location Name, no of Employee. Here i have drill
>   down from Organisation name --> Department name --> Location.

This doesn't really make sense.  If your report block already contains `Department Name` and `Location`, there would be little value in offering a drilldown from `Organization Name`.

Comment: @ Joe : Creating Context or shortcut join will help. But in my work i have to create alias and have to go forward with that. And the scenario Given is just a sample to know the hierarchy. So please don't take this as the actual scenario. Please help me know the hierarchy.

Comment: My answer was based on the scenario you described.  Sorry I couldn't help you.